# dojo how to have multiple rows in a datagrid header

Tags: datagrid, dojo

i need to have a datagrid with the following layout:

```
------------------------------------------------
|      |       |           player              |  
| date | time  |-------------------------------|
|      |       | first name | last name | age  |
|----------------------------------------------|
| jan  | 14:02 | roy        | batty     | 3    | 
|----------------------------------------------|
| mar  | 17:12 | pika       | chu       | 1    | 
|----------------------------------------------|
| dec  | 05:31 | louie      | dickens   | 33   | 
------------------------------------------------
```

Preliminary inquiries seem to reveal that dojo does not support this kind of behavior, am i right?

thank you very much

Comment: It is possible. You just have to specify the `rowSpan` for the header. See the [Documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/datagrid/).

Comment: @Himanshu the problem is that "colSpan cannot be defined on cells in the first sub-row. This is a because the DataGrid uses table-layout: fixed; to speed up the rendering of rows.". That prevents me from having the "player" cell on top of the "first name", "last name" and "age" cells

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in dojo, you need to use CompoundColumns feature for this and then you will achieve this.

Please follow this link,

[CompoundColumns for multilevel row in dojo grid](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/extensions/CompoundColumns.html)

Please do try this and do let me know if have any issue/concern.